# Error al momento de importar un documento de Excel a un datagridview c#

Tags: c#

Intentaba importar una tabla de un archivo de Excel a un `datagridview`. Aquí está mi código:

```
String ruta = "";

try
        {

            OpenFileDialog openfile2 = new OpenFileDialog();
            openfile2.Filter = "Excel (*.xls)|*.xls";
            openfile2.Title = "Seleccione el archivo de Excel";
            if (openfile2.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                if (openfile2.FileName.Equals("") == false)
                {
                    ruta = openfile2.FileName;
                }
            }
            string rfx = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + ruta + ";Extended Properties = \"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES\"; ";
            OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(rfx);
            OleDbDataAdapter myad = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from [" + hoja + "$]", conn);
            DataTable ta = new DataTable();
            myad.Fill(ta);
            dataGridView2.DataSource = ta;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
```

El error que me sale está abajo en la imagen. alguien sabe que podría ser?
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Pues eso que debes instalar ese motor en esa maquina para que se habra tu archivo, lo mejor es que habras el archivo usando otra libreria, o dll, pero si quieres intalar access aqui la liga https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255

Comment: revisa lo siguiente: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/es-ES/593510f9-2f1c-42cb-a088-ac382beb9fac/el-proveedor-quotmicrosoftaceoledb120quot-no-est-registrado-en-el-equipo-localsystemdata?forum=sqlserveres

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intenta esto  metodo

```
 DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    public void ExcelGridview(string hoja, string ruta)
    {
        try
        {
            string cadena = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" + @"Data Source=" + ruta + ";" + @"Extended Properties=" + '"' + "Excel 8.0;HDR=YES" + '"';

            OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(cadena);
            string strSQL = "SELECT * FROM ["+hoja+"$]";

            OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(strSQL, con);



            da.Fill(ds);

            dataGridView2.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
            con.Close();
            con.Dispose();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

    }
```

Dentro del evento de tu boton

```
OpenFileDialog openfile2= new OpenFileDialog();
openfile2.Filter = "Excel (*.xls)|*.xls";
        openfile2.Title = "Seleccione el archivo de Excel";
        if(openfile2.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            ruta = openfile2.FileName;
            ExcelGridview("Sheet1",ruta);//aqui le pasas el nombre de la hoja donde esta la informacion
        }
```

Me comenentas como te va...

Comment: muchas gracias.

Comment: me funcionó a la perfección te lo agradezco.